# Configuring dnsmasq to act as a IPv6-to-IPv4 or IPv4-to-IPv6 forwarder?

Tags: ipv6, internal-dns, forwarding, ipv4, dnsmasq

Is there a guide somewhere about how to rig up some IPv6-to-IPv4 and IPv4-to-IPv6.  I'd like to be able to run a dual stack on my home lan but not forfeit ipv4 just yet.

Comment: How would running dual stack forfeit ipv6?

Comment: Running Dual-Stack means exactly that - you're running two stacks of protocols. You will run IPv4 AND IPv6, both at the same time, neither of them being forfeited, and you won't need any IPv6-IPv4 translators, as you'll have them both natively.

Comment: dnsmasq 6-to-4 "translation" should "just work" when dnsmasq is installed on a dual-stack box. What problem do you get?

Comment: @Christopher Good point. I just meant that I didn't want to get rid of ipv4 yet (which is what a dual stack is for)

Comment: @Bittrance I don't have any problems yet, I'm just taking a stab in the dark at how to go about setting a dual stack network up (I've never done that before).  I've setup ipv4 networks in the past, but never an ipv6 or a dual stack network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue really is to set up an 6-to-4 router, and assuming that you can spare a Linux box as router/bridge, you want to do three things:

1. install radvd on the LAN side of the router.
2. setup a 6to4 tunnel to pass your IPv6 traffic over to IPv6 Internet
3. setup firewall rules for IPv6

`#PREFIX#` in the below examples is the IPv6 address from the 2002: prefix reserved for legacy addresses, which can be found with "ipv6calc --ipv4_to_6to4addr ".

radvd will do router advertisements on LAN side, telling all IPv6-capable hosts how to configure their IPv6 addresses. A typical radvd.conf may look like this:

```
interface eth1 {  
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   MinRtrAdvInterval 30;
   MaxRtrAdvInterval 60;

   prefix 0:0:0:1::/64 {
      AdvOnLink on;
      AdvAutonomous on;
      AdvRouterAddr off;
      AdvValidLifetime 86400;
      AdvPreferredLifetime 3600;
      Base6to4Interface eth0;
   };

   RDNSS #PREFIX#:1::1 {
      AdvRDNSSOpen on;
   };
};
```

A 6to4 tunnel can be created thus:

```
ip route add 2000::/3 via ::192.88.99.1 dev sit0
ip addr  add #PREFIX#:1::1/64 dev eth1
```

Finally, ip6tables is your friend. The above config assumes that there is a IPv6 capable DNS server on :1::1. dnsmasq should do fine.

Hope this will be enough information to get you googling on the right howtos.